# Measure of "Normalness"

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, histogram

My goal is to classify different portions of a signal. By dividing the signal to smaller windows and plotting the histogram of each division and fitting a normal distribution to the histograms, I realized that my portion of interest distribution does not have a normal distribution while the rest of the signal has. You can see an example below,
[image]
I am trying to come up with a method to **measure how close is a distribution to a normal distribution**.
So far, I tried the skewness, which could be a solution but it won't work properly in my case. 
As you can see below, I tried measuring sigma and mu of the distribution, yet I believe it is not really conclusive.
Moreover, I can fit a normal distribution to each histogram and calculate the mean square error of the histogram centers to the fitted normal distribution. Though, I couldn't find any source or example that mentions such a thing as a measure of how normal is a distribution.
Finally, I thought of using a chi-squared test instead of a mean square in the above method, yet I was not sure if it is applicable in this case.
My question is, is there a known method to determine how close is a distribution to a normal distribution? If there is not, what approach should I take?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test

Comment: Your data is not really skewed so skewnes is not going to tell you much. You can try to sompute the [kurtosis](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) instead.

Comment: Perhaps see [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432538/which-data-is-more-normal/432547#432547), and try using $D$ from the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of normality.

Comment: Thank you all!
The comments were quite helpful. I will try the mentioned methods by BruceET and user20160, and report the results.
I won't delete the question. I will test the methods and write a summary of the results as an answer to my own question, in order to share it with the community.

Comment: chi squared statistic is actually a long time used measure of similarity between distributions. and also mean square error of histograms is used sometimes.

Comment: Most of the histograms outside the red box *don't* really look normal to me. You may be better with some measure that responds to how flat the peak is in the red section compared to the peakiness outside it.  Note that the D in a K-S is insensitive to differences in the tail.